# Truncate NSDate (Zero-out time)

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, truncate

I want to generate a new `NSDate` with **0 hours**, **0 minutes**, and **0 seconds** for time. The source date can be any random `NSDate`.

Is there a way to achieve this? The documentation did not help me with this.

---

**Example**

Have: `2010-10-30 10:14:13 GMT`

Want: `2010-10-30 00:00:00 GMT`

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43121423/1966109) that offers up to four ways to solve your problem with Swift 3.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
unsigned int flags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay;
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:date];
NSDate* dateOnly = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

`date` is the date you want to remove the time from.

This separates the date and time and creates a new date with the default time (00:00:00).

**EDIT**

To take time zone into account:

```
NSDate* dateOnly = [[calendar dateFromComponents:components] dateByAddingTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]secondsFromGMT]];
```

Comment: it retained its hour value :o i get 19:00:00 from 19:27:23

Comment: Great answer. It is really stupid that commonly needed things like this are not included in `Foundation`.

Comment: This works well, but the reason I prefer using rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate: is that it's easier to generalize to find other date boundaries like year, minute, hour, etc. NSDateComponents requires that you work out the correct flags for each case.

Comment: why 22:00:00 is default hour ? it depends on timezone?

Comment: Yes, there is a matter of the timezone. If you are GMT, it will return 00:00:00. See my edit.

Comment: my real timezone is CET (Central Europe Time) 
DebugLog(@"Today: %@", [NSDate date]); said GMT (wrote in console)

Comment: I have tested random dates and times. All results have had the original date and a time of 00:00:00.

Comment: yeah, okay, thank you very much, now i can do this on my own, that was very helpful, i'm grateful.

Comment: I'm getting 01:00:00. I'm guessing that's the same issue as Benjamin's - must need to adjust for daylight savings also.

Comment: None of the answers on truncating date/time components worked for me without setting `[calendarInstance setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];` before extracting the components. I have answered it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31278150/3056278 for a similar question as to why it is so.

Answer (score 17):

Use NSCalendar's `rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:`. This code will choose the day boundary based on the current time zone. If you want a particular time zone, you need to create an NSCalendar and set its time zone appropriately.

```
- (NSDate*)boundaryForCalendarUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)calendarUnit
{
    NSDate *boundary;
    [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:calendarUnit startDate:&boundary interval:NULL forDate:self];
    return boundary;
}

- (NSDate*)dayBoundary
{
    return [self boundaryForCalendarUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit];
}
```

Comment: +1 I like this better than the accepted answer. It doesn't run into problems with daylight savings and doesn't require a hack to take time zone into account.

Comment: +1 @rob great solution. Evan's accepted answer slowed my app down (around **1642.0ms** CPU-Time in ['Instruments'](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH1-SW1) 'Time Profiler' for each method call) whereas rob's solution fasted up to around **100.0ms**.

Comment: Interesting answer, but I don't think it addresses the question completely. You can get the correct output my setting the timezone to gmt. One way is to do this: 

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];

Comment: If you use this, and pass [NSDate date] as the argument you'll get the date in the GMT timezone, NOT your local timezone. If you want just the date in the local / system timezone use the accepted answer. Also note that the debugger will show something like this: __NSTaggedDate * 2015-09-10 00:00:00 UTC which is slightly confusing because it shows "UTC", but since the time is zero anyway the UTC is irrelevant.

Comment: @MarkEdington UTC = GMT and yes it is relevant :) NSDate has no custom time zone as it is always saved in UTC / GMT. While the accepted answer and this answer both support the users time zone out of the box, this one is much cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

With Swift 3, you can choose one of the **four following patterns** in order to solve your problem.

---

#### #1. Using `Calendar` `startOfDay(for:)`

[`startOfDay(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar/2293783-startofday) has the following declaration:

```
func startOfDay(for date: Date) -> Date
```

> Returns the first moment of a given `Date`, as a `Date`.

The Playground code below shows how to use this method:

```
import Foundation

let date = Date()

// Get new date
let calendar = Calendar.current
let newDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)

// Format dates
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK")
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long

let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
let formattedNewDate = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate)

// Print formatted dates
print(formattedDate) // Prints: 30/03/2017, 15:14:41 CEST
print(formattedNewDate) // Prints: 30/03/2017, 00:00:00 CEST
```

---

#### #2. Using `Calendar` `date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)`

[`date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar/2293479-date) has the following declaration:

```
func date(bySettingHour hour: Int, minute: Int, second: Int, of date: Date, matchingPolicy: Calendar.MatchingPolicy = default, repeatedTimePolicy: Calendar.RepeatedTimePolicy = default, direction: Calendar.SearchDirection = default) -> Date?
```

> Returns a new `Date` representing the date calculated by setting hour, minute, and second to a given time on a specified `Date`.

The Playground code below shows how to use this method:

```
import Foundation

let date = Date()

// Get new date
let calendar = Calendar.current
let newDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)

// Format dates
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK")
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long

let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
let formattedNewDate = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate!)

// Print formatted dates
print(formattedDate) // Prints: 30/03/2017, 15:14:41 CEST
print(formattedNewDate) // Prints: 30/03/2017, 00:00:00 CEST
```

---

#### #3. Using `Calendar` `dateComponents(_:from:)` and `date(from:)` methods

[`dateComponents(_:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar/2293646-datecomponents) has the following declaration:

```
func dateComponents(_ components: Set<Calendar.Component>, from date: Date) -> DateComponents
```

> Returns all the date components of a date, using the calendar time zone.

[`date(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar/2292916-date) has the following declaration:

```
func date(from components: DateComponents) -> Date?
```

> Returns a date created from the specified components.

The Playground code below shows how to use those methods:

```
import Foundation

let date = Date()

// Get new date
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: date)
let newDate = calendar.date(from: components)

// Format dates
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK")
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long

let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
let formattedNewDate = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate!)

// Print formatted dates
print(formattedDate) // Prints: 30/03/2017, 15:14:41 CEST
print(formattedNewDate) // Prints: 30/03/2017, 00:00:00 CEST
```

---

#### #4. Using `NSCalendar` `range(of:start:interval:for:)`

[`range(of:start:interval:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1408013-range) has the following declaration:

```
func range(of unit: NSCalendar.Unit, start datep: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDate?>?, interval tip: UnsafeMutablePointer<TimeInterval>?, for date: Date) -> Bool
```

> Returns by reference the starting time and duration of a given calendar unit that contains a given date.

The Playground code below shows how to use this method:

```
import Foundation

let date = Date()

// Get new date
let calendar = Calendar.current as NSCalendar
var newDate: NSDate?
calendar.range(of: .day, start: &newDate, interval: nil, for: date)

// Format dates
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK")
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long

let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
let formattedNewDate = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate as! Date)

// Print formatted dates
print(formattedDate) // Prints: 30/03/2017, 15:14:41 CEST
print(formattedNewDate) // Prints: 30/03/2017, 00:00:00 CEST
```

Answer (score 3):

I know its late, but there are now better methods:
why dont you just use

**Swift 2**

```
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateBySettingHour(0, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: yourDateToZeroOutTime, options: [])
```

**Swift 5**

```
var yourDate = Date() //Or any Date
yourDate  = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: yourDate) ?? yourDate
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
extension Date {
    func trimTime() -> Date {
        var boundary = Date()
        var interval: TimeInterval = 0
        _ = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .day, start: &boundary, interval: &interval, for: self)

        return Date(timeInterval: TimeInterval(NSTimeZone.system.secondsFromGMT()), since: boundary)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the description method to get the given date as a string, then modify the string and create your new date with initWithString.

initWithString:
Returns an NSDate object initialized with a date and time value specified by a given string in the international string representation format.

- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)description
  Parameters
  description
  A string that specifies a date and time value in the international string representation format—YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM, where ±HHMM is a time zone offset in hours and minutes from GMT (for example, “2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600”).
  You must specify all fields of the format string, including the time zone offset, which must have a plus or minus sign prefix.
  Return Value
  An NSDate object initialized with a date and time value specified by aString.

Comment: nm, evan's solution is better

Comment: This is a bad idea. If you really want to modify the date component-wise there is Evan's solution for that. I don't want to pull the performance card on such a small topic but well... string processing is comparatively expensive. If you just want to get the start of the day (or the "base date" for a day) for calculations, filtering etc - use Rob's version as it is even cleaner.