# Sort NSDate in order while ignoring time

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want to sort an array of NSDates only on their day month and year so not on any of the units of time. How can I do this because I can't see a way of getting the individual parts of an NsDate "out".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this post for sorting an array containing NSDate objects:

[Sort NSArray of date strings or objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects/1134126#1134126)

and mine for removing the time:

[Truncate NSDate (Zero-out time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187478/truncate-nsdate-objective-c/4187557#4187557)

**ADDITION**

1) Loop through your array of NSDate objects, removing (zeroing) the time components, and adding them to a new array:

```
NSMutableArray *newDateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDate *d in myDateArray)
{
    unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:d];
    //Taking the time zone into account
    NSDate *dateOnly = [[calendar dateFromComponents:components] dateByAddingTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]secondsFromGMT]];
    [newDateArray addObject:dateOnly];
}
```

2) Now that you have a new array consisting of NSDate objects with zeroed time components, you can sort them:

```
[newDateArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

This line sorts the array using the NSDate object's own comparator method.