# Sorting of Date String using sortUsingDescriptors?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nssortdescriptor

I have number of arrays of dictionary

```
   points = 200;
   startDate = "Jun 04, 2011, 13:15 PM";

   points = 200;
   startDate = "May 01, 2011, 11:15 PM";

   and  -------
```

I have to do sorting on the basis of startDate.

I have used number of sorting's earlier like numerical.. alphabetical sorting etc via this method:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)SortEventsArray:(NSMutableArray*)arrayToSort :(NSString*)sortExpression
{
   NSSortDescriptor *mySorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortExpression ascending:YES];
   [arrayToSort sortUsingDescriptors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:mySorter]];
   return arrayToSort;
}
```

but its not working for Date string.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chekout this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355765/sort-nsdate-in-order-while-ignoring-time)

[This one also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects)

Both will help you.