# How to know two dates are same

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

HI i have two date pickers.

datepicker1, datepicker2.

I need datepicker1.date to compare with datepicker2.date

i need to verify that the two dates are same or not . How is it possible. Thanks in advance.i have used the below one but it is not working

```
if([datePicker.date isEqualToDate:FromPicker.date])
```

Comment: You can look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7736757/443292). I would recommend you research before you post such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to ignore time component. Do it by below way:

```
 NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *components1 = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                                       fromDate:YOUR_FIRST_DATE];
 NSDateComponents *components2 = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                                        fromDate:YOUR_SECOND_DATE];

 if ([components1 year] == [components2 year] &&
     [components1 month] == [components2 month] &&
     [components1 day] == [components2 day]) 
 {
           //dates are same...
 }
 else
 {
           //dates are different...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard comparison method, [compare:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare%3a)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-compare:` method of NSDate:

```
if([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedSame)
{
    //They are the sme    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using `timeIntervalSince1970`

```
NSDate *date1; // your first date
NSDate *date2; // your second date

if ([date1 timeIntervalSince1970] == [date2 timeIntervalSince1970]) {
    //Equal
}
```