# Creating a future date in swift with NSDate()

Tags: swift, nscalendar

I'm getting an error: "Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call" for the following code:

```
var components = NSDateComponents()     
components.setValue(1,forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth);
var expirationDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components,       toDate: NSDate(),options:0)
```

The docs calls for:

```
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(<#comps: NSDateComponents?#>, toDate: <#NSDate?#>, options: <#NSCalendarOptions#>)
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing? I don't see a parameter named 'coder' required.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

how it looks to be with

## swift 4.x

```
let date = Date()
var components = DateComponents()
components.setValue(1, for: .month)
let expirationDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: date)
```

---

#### swift 2.0

```
let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
components.setValue(1, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.Month);
let date: NSDate = NSDate()
let expirationDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

---

#### swift 1.2

```
var components = NSDateComponents()
components.setValue(1, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth);
let date: NSDate = NSDate()
var expirationDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))
```

---

#### Objective-C

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate new];  
NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
components.month = 1;
NSDate *expirationDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
```

Comment: Don't understand what the error meant, especially the "coder" part, but your fix worked. Gracias.

Comment: I would not like to be a smart-ass to say some clever thing – regarding _Xcode6_ is still beta only – but I presume the issue was the `NSDate` was inited as embedded parameter, and the compiler wanted to call the `NSDate(coder:)` method  for it instead of the `NSDate()` for some reason. that could be the reason of you had the error message about the missing `coder:` parameter.

Comment: Update for Swift 2.0 - change the options value to:  `NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0)`

Comment: You can also just use `[]` instead of `NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0)`

Answer (score 12):

Syntax for Swift 3

```
var components = DateComponents()
components.setValue(1, forComponent: .month)
let date: Date = Date()
let expirationDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: date, options: [])
```

Answer (score 6):

Latest **Swift 3** syntax:

```
var components = DateComponents()
components.setValue(1, for: .month)
let date: Date = Date()
let expirationDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: date)
```

Comment: Works beautifully in Swift 4.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 version**

```
var components = DateComponents()
components.setValue(1, for: .month)
let date: Date = Date()
let expirationDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: date, wrappingComponents: false)
```

Hope this helps!