# Comparing date string from today's date in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to compare a given date which is in string with today's date

```
func getDateFromDateString(date: String) -> Date {
      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
      dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "yyyy-MM-dd"//"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
      let date = dateFormatter.date(from:date) ?? Date()
    return date
}


let ticketDate = getDateFromDateString(date: "2023-04-04")
        
let currentDate = Date()

if currentDate >  ticketDate {
  print("Expired")
} else {
  print("Active")
}
```

The result should be Active but it's Expired I don't know why

Comment: Date also contains a time component

Comment: what's the solution, because I want to ignore the time comparison

Comment: You can extract the date components an you can compare them...

Comment: You could try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324633/nsdate-beginning-of-day-and-end-of-day) to set the time to the start or end of the day

Comment: the code you show gives me the correct answer.
             When did you try this? Yesterday or today (2023-04-04).
             If I change the string to "2023-04-10", then I get `Active`,
             because it represents a date ahead of `currentDate`. Otherwise
             I get `Expired`. Note a `Date` is in GMT/UTC time, not local time.

Comment: When does it expire, 2023-04-04 00:00:00 or 2023-04-04 23:59:59?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line

```
if currentDate > ticketDate {
```

with

```
if Calendar.current.compare(currentDate, 
                            to: ticketDate, 
                            toGranularity: .day) == .orderedAscending {
```

it compares the dates ignoring less significant date components than `day`

Answer (score 0):

Replaced code by these

```
func getDateFromDateString(dateString: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    return date
}

func todayDate() -> Date{
    let currentDate = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let year = calendar.component(.year, from: currentDate)
    let month = calendar.component(.month, from: currentDate)
    let day = calendar.component(.day, from: currentDate)

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = year
    dateComponents.month = month
    dateComponents.day = day

    let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
    return date
}

let currentDate = todayDate()

let ticketDate = getDateFromDateString(dateString: "2023-04-04")!

if ticketDate >= currentDate {
    print("Active")
} else {
    print("Expired")
}
```

On your code current date have time as well so please remove time from today date. So it's compare with time which it will found greater and print as **Expired**. For better solution please use full date i.e. with time. If you want to know more please comment. I am happy to explain.

Comment: You can replace the function `todayDate()` with the built-in function [startOfDay(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293783-startofday)