# Objective-c how to get a date with no time components at GMT timezone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, timezone, nsdate

I got a code snippet that takes a date and tries to convert it into a date without time components. I then use this trimmed data to do saving/fetching from core data.

```
-(NSDate*)dateWithNoTimeComponents:(NSDate*)startDate
{

    //
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSNumber* count = 0;
    int secondsPerDay = 86400;


    //break the date and create fractional components for that date
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit| NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:startDate];

    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    NSInteger second = [components second];

    //update daily count
    //remove fractional componets from the date, effectively creating a key per day
    return  [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-((hour*60+minute)*60+second) sinceDate:startDate];
}
```

My concern is that this might not work with dates from different time zones. Would putting dates from different timestamps affect this method? For example, if I'm in the GMT -5 timezone, then move into GMT -8 timezone, would the trimmed date produced by this method still be correct?  **Do I need to include the timezone offset/daylight savings somewhere in this calculation to make it globally correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing to do is follow the SDK convention of doing everything in GMT, only converting to local timezones for the user to see.

Your code does math on hours and minutes, which leaves open the chance for errors on edge cases.  It's better let the sdk do the math.  To get the zero hour of a given date, try something like this...

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:startDate];
NSDate *justTheDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: Great answer, I totally missed that I can use only year, month and day for the date without time

Answer (score 0):

I also used to take the same solution as [danh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294949/danh) but it was **too time consuming** (about **1642.0ms** CPU-Time in [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH1-SW1)' 'Time Profiler'). It slowed my whole app down using it several times.

Finally I found  **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187478/truncate-nsdate-zero-out-time/4187569#4187569)** and used it in my final method:

```
// this method takes around 100ms CPU-time (measured with instruments)
- (NSDate*) truncateDate : (NSDate*) date
          toCalendarUnit : (NSCalendarUnit) calendarUnit 
{
    NSDate *truncatedDate;
    [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit : calendarUnit
                                    startDate : &truncatedDate
                                     interval : NULL
                                      forDate : date];
    return truncatedDate;
}
```

This method took only around **100.0ms** CPU-Time.

For me, this is a better solution.